# Is there a way to remove a lot of signatures or taglines of a great number of answers?

Tags: support, specific-question, signatures

Have Moderators a "tool" to remove signatures from differents answers?

EDIT:
Now I'm a moderator of Electronics and Robotics (E&R). E&R was merged with Chiphacker. There is a user that put signature in about 160 answers when in Chiphacker, that there wasn't this policy.

I'd like to know if there is a tool to remove them or we have to edit one by one.

Comment: I say no, they don't. Otherwise there would be no reason why they haven't used it yet.

Comment: Is this the **same signature** on a huge number of posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have Moderators a "tool" to remove signatures from differents answers?

Nope, sorry.